# Why tr of table cannot be displayed orderly in primefaces

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, html-table

I have encountered a problem.It is that I want to place a multiSelectListbox at bottom of table(not dataTable). However, when I do it,
 the multiSelectListbox is displayed on the top of table.

The below is my codes:

```
<table id="addBookTable" class="common_tab" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th><span style="color: red;">*</span>BookName:</th>
        <td><p:inputText styleClass="inputTextClass" id="input_text_1"
                placeholder="Input book name" value="#{bookView.newBook.name}"
                onblur="onLeave(this)">
            </p:inputText></td>
        <td>
            <h:outputLabel styleClass="errorTipClass" value="book name must be not empty"
             id="errorTip1" binding="#{errorTip1}"/>
        </td>
        <th><span style="color: red;">*</span>ISBN:</th>
        <td><p:inputText styleClass="inputTextClass" id="input_text_2"
                onkeypress="return (/[\d.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)))"
                placeholder="Input book's ISBN" maxlength="13" value="#{bookView.newBook.isbn}"
                onblur="onLeave(this)">
            </p:inputText></td>
        <td><p:outputLabel  styleClass="errorTipClass" value="Must be thirteen bits number" 
        id="errorTip2" binding="#{errorTip2}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><span style="color: red;">*</span>author:</th>
        <td><p:inputText styleClass="inputTextClass" id="input_text_3"
                placeholder="Input book's author" value="#{bookView.newBook.author}"
                onblur="onLeave(this)"/></td>
        <td><p:outputLabel  styleClass="errorTipClass" value="author must be not empty" 
        id="errorTip3"  binding="#{errorTip3}" /></td>
        <th><span style="color: red;">*</span>press:</th>
        <td><p:inputText styleClass="inputTextClass" id="input_text_4"
                placeholder="Input book's press" value="#{bookView.newBook.press}"
                onblur="onLeave(this)"/></td>
        <td><p:outputLabel  styleClass="errorTipClass" value="press must be not empty"
         id="errorTip4" binding="#{errorTip4}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><span style="color: red;">*</span>price:</th>
        <td><p:inputText styleClass="inputTextClass" id="input_text_5"
                style="text-align:right;" placeholder="Input book's price" 
                value="#{bookView.newBook.price}" onblur="onLeave(this)"/></td>
        <td><p:outputLabel  styleClass="errorTipClass" value="Input is invalid" 
        id="errorTip5" binding="#{errorTip5}" /></td>
        <th><span style="color: red;">*</span>Publication Date:</th>
        <td><p:calendar effect="fold" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" navigator="true"
                yearRange="c-50:#{bookView.currentYear}" lang="zh_CN"
                id="newBookPublicationDate" placeholder="Choice book's date of publication"
                onblur="this.style.border = '2px green solid'" readonlyInput="true"
                value="#{bookView.newBookDate}" style="height:25px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <p:multiSelectListbox value="#{bookView.newBook.category}" effect="slide" header="Categories" showHeaders="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bookView.categories}" />
        </p:multiSelectListbox>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I will be appreciated if you can help me, although an advice.

Comment: This question is not jsf, PrimeFaces or java-ee related. It is a plain html problem. It would have failed with a plain html input or div or whatever. You **need** a td or th inside a tr... plain and simple

Comment: Yeah.This question is just a plain html problem.I have tried the method as your advice before  I post this question.However,it not work.Using colspan attribute can solve this question.

Comment: @Emil Alkalay Please do not improper tags. Read the tag description first!

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your multiselectlistbox in cell.In your case you will need to colspan:

```
<tr><td colspan="5">
    <p:multiSelectListbox value="#{bookView.newBook.category}" effect="slide" header="Categories" showHeaders="true">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bookView.categories}" />
    </p:multiSelectListbox
 </td></tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried to apply this method and succeeded to solve it after I post this question.The reason why the multiSelectListBox cannot be displayed as my design is that attribute colspan of tag td is 1 by default.Thank you for your enthusiastic answer.